# How can I use wp_insert_comment to write a comment when a post is edited?

Tags: php, functions

This would mean that when post A was edited by User1, a new comment would appear under post A that reads 'edited by User1', so that the post edit history can easily be seen. A link to the post revision could also be useful here.

Perhaps wp_new_comment would be a better choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following code in the functions.php file of your [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) theme.

```
function add_comment_on_post_update( $post_id, $post_after, $post_before ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;
    if (isset($post_before->post_status) && 'auto-draft' == $post_before->post_status) {
        return;
    }

    if ('post' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $comment = 'Edited by '.$current_user->user_login;

        $time = current_time('mysql');

        $data = array(
            'comment_post_ID' => $post_id,
            'comment_author' => 'admin',
            'comment_author_email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'comment_author_url' => 'http://www.xyz.com',
            'comment_content' => $comment,
            'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
            'comment_date' => $time,
            'comment_approved' => 1,
            'comment_type' => 'custom-comment-class'
        );
        wp_insert_comment($data);
    }

}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'add_comment_on_post_update', 10 , 3 );
```

Best Regards,
Vinod Dalvi

Comment: This works excellently. Although it doesn't seem to work if the update is made using p2? p2 uses the following function to save posts http://cl.ly/code/2S403f1l3n1h

Comment: More importantly can we add a class to these comments so that I can style them? e.g. class='revision-notice'?

Comment: I have updated the above code to add custom-comment-class class to these comments so that it can be styled differently.